# Connection pooling Glassfish 3 or Tomcat 7?

Tags: performance, glassfish-3, connection-pooling, tomcat7

I want to know which connection pool is faster and allows maximum connections Glassfish 3 or Tomcat 7? What is the maximum number of connections that Glassfish 3 and Tomacat 7 allow at a particular time ?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the maximum number of connections that Glassfish 3 and Tomacat
>   7 allow at a particular time ?

you cannot google this ?

> I want to know which connection pool is faster

Here on stackoverflow we encourage subjective questions and answers. Can you please perhaps frame a better questions.

Comment: I of course googled it but could not find anything on the topic. This question is practical and performance related . Please contributing some productive answer if you can.